# Traversing table elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-traversal

I have a table structure as :

```
<table id = "cust-id">
  <tr>
    <td> 1</td>
    <td id = "specific_id_re"><a href = "#">link tag</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 2 </td>
    <td id = "specific_id"> <a href = "#">link tag</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to use jquery to access each of the table row columns that have an id and a link tag, but I am falling short. The best I have been doing is:

```
 $('#cust-id').children().children().children() ; // to get access to the td elements ?
```

Any suggestions on what I should read or how I ought to approach this ?

Thanks
Parijat Kalia

Comment: Those TD elements are in the 2. column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#cust-id td[id] a').each(function () {
  var td = $(this).closest('td');
  // do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#cust-id tr:has(td[id] a)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cust-id td')
```

will gather all the `td` elements under the element with `#cust-id`. You can chain the selectors the same as in regular CSS.

If you want the *row* parents of a `<td>` you can traverse back up from the `<td>` using

```
$('#cust-id td').closest('tr')
```

Ah, you actually want just those `<td>` that have `<a>` and an `id`, so...

```
$('#cust-id td[id] a').closest('td')
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects all TD elements that are in the 2. column:

```
$( 'td:nth-child(2)', '#cust-id' )
```

This selects all TD elements that have an "id" attribute:

```
$( 'td[id]', '#cust-id' )
```

This selects all TD elements that contain a `<a>` element:

```
$( 'td:has(a)', '#cust-id' )
```

So, if you combine those approaches, you can select those TD element that (1) have an "id" attribute, and (2) contain a `<a>` element:

```
$( 'td[id]:has(a)', '#cust-id' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector $('#cust-id td[id]') this will return all td elements that has id attribute.